# Select Random Objects with Name

Tags: selection-tools

I have many objects with the same name. I can search for these in the `Collection` window. I would like to select a random subset of these.

I can see that Blender 2.8 has a `Select -> Select Random` option, but this includes all visible objects.

Comment: How about hiding all other objects temporarily?

Comment: @Leander That would be an option. Is there a way to do this without 'un-hiding' any already hidden objects when making the original objects visible again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use select random and then [run a script](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html) that deselects anything that doesn't match the name that you specify.

```
import bpy

for o in bpy.context.visible_objects:
    if 'gizmo' not in o.name.lower():
        o.select_set(False)
```

Another way could be to make a list of objects matching the name criteria and then getting a [random choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) from that list and selecting them.

```
import bpy
from random import choices

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

objlist = [o for o in bpy.context.visible_objects
            if 'gizmo' in o.name.lower()]

rand_list = choices(objlist, k=int(len(objlist) * .75))

for o in rand_list:
    o.select_set(True)
```

In this example, I set the k parameter to be 75% of the object list. You could also specify an exact number of objects that you want selected.